# How do I display the Contact ID on User Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, user-dashboard, contact-reference

MAYYYBE I am over complicating this, but I have searched and searched and only found this answered for Drupal.

We are on Wordpress and would like for members to provide me with a searchable unique id. Obviously, that means the Contact ID would be best. I am just struggling with an easy way to integrate this SINGLE piece of info into the user dashboard.

I really just want it to say something like: Your Contact ID is: ### at the top of the dashboard so people aren't freaked out by looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you could do this:

Create a report that shows the contact ID and name, make that report available on a user dashboard, then you can use the [dashlet](https://civicrm.org/extensions/default-dashlets) extension to place the dashlet on the end-user dashboard.

Take the Contact IDs and reimport them as the External ID, then display that in the Contact Dashboard as part of the member profile.

Write some code to pull the ID out of the database and display it graphically as part of a Membership Card. I do this on one of my Joomla sites but there's no reason why it can't work in Wordpress.

Example: [image]

Comment: OMG! We have been looking for EXACTLY that card for a while! I even have a topic that I created about a year ago for it.

Comment: The report I am afraid will display more than just their own information, but the Contact Dashboard and the Membership card would be ideal.

Comment: I can send you the code for this, but it will need to be adjusted to work in Wordpress.